# Warning message on Probit analysis R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a probit analysis  for some mortality tests to get an LT50. This data set is for one insect. State is either dead (1) or alive (0) for the different times.

```
> mbugdata
   state time
1      0   10
2      0   20
3      1   30
4      1   40
5      1   50
6      1   60
7      1   70
8      1   80
9      1   90
10     1  100

y<-cbind(mbugdata$state)
x<-cbind(mbugdata$time)
myprobit <- glm(state~time,family=binomial(link="probit"),data=mbugdata)
```

However I keep getting these warning messages

```
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Could someone please help me? (I am new to R)

Comment: You have a separation issue: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_%28statistics%29

Comment: It really makes very little sense to talk about an LT50 for a single bug. There no way that the critter cam be 50% dead.

Comment: This is also not a R problem. It needs to be migrated to cross-validated to determine a correct method of analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an R problem, it's a statistical problem. You have problems of overfitting, separation, etc, etc.

You should revise your statistical model specification to avoid the error.

If you can provide a copy of your data then I can illustrate this, but it would be best to write a post at CrossValidated which details your data and research question.

There's also some canned ways of avoiding this issue, such as the use of the package `bestglm` which involve automated selection of the statistical model.

```
install.packages("bestglm")
require(bestglm)
```

Here's an [example](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html) of its usage.